# jQuery: How do I pass a value into an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am updating some div as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var query = base_url + data[i];
    $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 2000,
        error: function() { self.html("Network Error"); },
        success: function(json) {
            $("#li" + i).html("<img src='" + json.result.list[0].url + "' />")
        }
    });
}
```

The value of i does not work inside the ajax call. I am trying to pass the value of i so that it can attach the element to the proper div. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Just curious, stepping back a level, is firing off `n` ajax requests the only way to do what you're after?  Can this not be done as a batch in one round-trip?  This would be a much better and more responsive user experience.

Comment: @Reigel: Fixed it thanks.     
@Nick: Sorry but could you explain that a little more? I am open to a better approach.

Comment: It would be better to submit your data in one shot to the server, then use an object that comes back and loop through it to get whatever response values you need...do you have control over the server-side this is hitting to do that?

Comment: @Nick: Nopes :( I can only request multiple JSON objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This works but would really love if someone can explain it! I broke my head over this so posting it here just in case someone needs it.

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
   fetchItem(i)

fetchItem = function(i) {
    var query = base_url + data[i]; 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: query, 
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        timeout: 2000, 
        error: function() { self.html("Network Error"); }, 
        success: function(json) { 
            $("#li" + i).html("<img src='" + json.result.list[0].url + "' />") 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: This works because you created a closure which copies `i`, if in your `success` callback you wrapped it in a closure it'd also work, like this: `(function(j) { return function(json) { $("#li" + j).html("<img src='" + json.result.list[0].url + "' />"); })(i)`

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for helping me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making i a global variable:

Change:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    var query = base_url + data[i]; 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: query, 
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        timeout: 2000, 
        error: function() { self.html("Network Error"); }, 
        success: function(json) { 
            $("#li" + i).html("<img src='" + json.result.list[0].url + "' />") 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

To this:

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    var query = base_url + data[i]; 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: query, 
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        timeout: 2000, 
        error: function() { self.html("Network Error"); }, 
        success: function(json) { 
            $("#li" + i).html("<img src='" + json.result.list[0].url + "' />") 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Also I agree with Nick. You can do the looping first then send the array (JSON) serverside to be processed. This way the application will be much more responsive.

Comment: Yes. Just after posting my question.

Comment: I am not disagreeing. Just that I don't have control over the server.

Comment: Legend - Oh I see..maybe making i global may help out

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried that but in vain. I posted something that works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has to do with scope.

You should wrap the what's in the for loop into a function

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   doAjax(i);
}

function doAjax(i) {
 var query = base_url + data[i];
    $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 2000,
        error: function() { self.html("Network Error"); },
        success: function(json) {
            $("#li" + i).html("<img src='" + json.result.list[0].url + "' />")
        }
    });
}
```

The `i` value for the closure function of `success` is correctly bound only when it is not in a for loop.

That should work. Good luck.

Comment: Hah. I guess someone posted the same thing. :)